# In Visual Studio can i plot my variable in breakpoint ?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

In Visual Studio for my native C++ program I want to get a plot of some variables during debug. Mostly I use textual representation of the objects by editing autoexp.dat. But for some of the variables it is better to have a plot rather than having values in textual form.

So far I have used a function `plot(const void* address,const char* type)` , and called it from *Immediate Window* giving the variable address & the type, and internally casting it to proper type.

But this method has two disadvantages:

- First is that, function overloading almost never works when calling a function from debugger (so I had to pass type as a second parameter), and the function call occasionally crashes, though it works perfectly when called from within code.
- Second is, instead of writing a C++ function for plotting, I am interested to have a scripting language (like autoexp.dat or a VBScript) to give the internal data of the C++ object *without writing* any wrapper, so that I can use the script to store the data in a file or plot it.

In general I am interested to have something like *Matlab* or *Ch IDE*, where I can plot certain variable externally when the program is at a debug break.

Comment: When you say "plot", do you mean having all kind of informations about variables while in a debug break? It's not very clear...

Comment: In general term using "plot" I mean to have access to all data of the variable/object available to me so that I can represent it in any form (like storing in a file in a particular format)
In this particular context, "plot" means just plot it on screen (like i can plot an vector/ array as a 2D plot)

Answer (score 3):

Since VS 2005, Visual Studio has included [Visualizers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx), which could almost have been designed specifically for your problem. MSDN explains the concept better than I can:

> Visualizers are a new component of the
>   Visual Studio debugger user interface.
>   A visualizer creates a dialog box or
>   other interface to displays a variable
>   or object in a meaningful way that is
>   appropriate to its data type. For
>   example, an HTML visualizer interprets
>   an HTML string and displays the result
>   as it would appear in a browser
>   window, a bitmap visualizer interprets
>   a bitmap structure and displays the
>   graphic it represents, and so on. Some
>   visualizers allow you to edit as well
>   as view the data.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2zc529c.aspx) for a tutorial on how to write one.

Comment: Visualizers are good. But unfortunately I hadn't found any proper way to use it for native C++ application. They are for .NET based applications.

Comment: Mixed C++ / C++CLI app? It seems the restirction exists because the debuggee side of the Visualizer needs to expose a .NET interface. It shouldn't matter where it gets its data from.

Answer (score 2):

You can plot variables in real-time charts with [NetDebugPlot](http://www.shazbits.com/netdebugplot) and [NetDebugLog](http://www.shazbits.com/netdebuglog).

```
#include "NetDebugLog.h"

NetLog(myvar);
NetLog("test", myvar2);
```

[image: NetDebugPlot]

Comment: this is nice one but, NetDebugPlot program keeps crashing

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, I'm not sure exactly what do you wish to plot. I usually understand, when someone says he wants to "plot something", he usually means some array with numerical values.
If this is true in your case, Intel's [Array Visualizer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-array-visualizer) is maybe of some help. It can be downloaded freely, it integrates into visual studio, and you can use it in two ways: as a standalone application or while debugging ("while in some breakpoint") so you can plot array values "while program is running".

Answer (score 0):

Could you use [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) for this?  Spit out the data you want to plot as debug prints, and then while you're sitting at a breakpoint, copy it to an external file and run it through the plotter.