# Is it difficult for a visual studio addin to read object values during a debug session?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

I spend a lot of time debugging code for a CAD/CAM application. There are many times when I look at a variable in a watch window that has a long list of data points. Sometimes it's quite difficult to do a spot check making sure the data points actually make sense.

I'd love to create a visual studio addin in which during a debug session I can highlight a variable in code, or perhaps in a watch window, that contains a list of points. Then I could right click into a context menu (or some other menu) and select my brand new "Plot Points" Addin.

I don't have any experience creating Visual Studio Addins, and from the little research I've done, it isn't clear if this is even possible.

Does anyone have a suggestion, example, or idea related to my idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and not too difficult to pull off. What you're describing falls into the realm of a [VS Debug Visualizers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx).

Also, this is mostly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494911/in-visual-studio-can-i-plot-my-variable-in-breakpoint).